# Открыть Form2 по нажатию на кнопку, а после закрытия открыть Form1 заново

Tags: c#, windows, .net, forms

Хотел реализовать открытие Form2 по нажатию на кнопку, а после закрытия открыть Form1 заново, но у меня открытие Form1 заново не происходит.

Как быть?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RAIS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void обАвтореToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выполнил Ващинский Иван Сергеевич 292а, 2022г. " +
               "Основанием для разработки проекта служит задание выданное преподавателем Притула Ж.В.", "Об авторе",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK,
               MessageBoxIcon.Information
               );
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form ifrm = new Form2();
            ifrm.Left = this.Left; // задаём открываемой форме позицию слева равную позиции текущей формы
            ifrm.Top = this.Top; // задаём открываемой форме позицию сверху равную позиции текущей формы
            ifrm.Show(); // отображаем Form2
            this.Hide(); // скрываем Form1 (this - текущая форма)
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RAIS
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // вызываем главную форму, которая открыла текущую, главная форма всегда = 0 - [0]
            Form ifrm = Application.OpenForms[0];
            ifrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; // меняем параметр StartPosition у Form1, иначе она будет использовать тот, который у неё прописан в настройках и всегда будет открываться по центру экрана
            ifrm.Left = this.Left; // задаём открываемой форме позицию слева равную позиции текущей формы
            ifrm.Top = this.Top; // задаём открываемой форме позицию сверху равную позиции текущей формы
            ifrm.Show(); // отображаем Form1
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: вместо `Form ifrm = Application.OpenForms[0];` нужно `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` где Form1 -имя первой формы, а потом уже скрываем не нужную форму `this.Hide();`  и показываем нужную `form1.Show();`

Comment: @Георгий это создаст клон основной формы, а не вернет на экран исходную форму. Плохой совет.

Comment: @aepot, благодарю что поправил, буду знать

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике событий закрытия второй формы напишите код, подобный этому

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); f2.Show(); Hide();
```